# What is the most lightweight way to load an unloaded attribute for an object?

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2

As an example, say I would want to change the filter navigation for categories to add a `title` attribute to the links generated. The file

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml
```

contains the category object (`$_category`). However, the attribute `meta_title` isn't loaded for that object.

Straight forward, I could load a second category object, but that loads a lot of attributes that `$_category` already contains.

So I'm looking for the most lightweight way to load additional attributes for a given object, and best would be without loading a new object of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, calling `load` for each category is a performance killer.
Also loading an attribute for a category separately does not scale, because you will have to do a query for each category.
So you can just add the attribute to the category collection when the collection is loaded.
Here is the stack trace of what happens.

In `/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml` this method is called to retrieve the categories. `<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>` where `$this` is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation`.
Inside this method at one point `$category->getChildrenCategories()` is called where `$category` is the current category object that is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category`.
The method `getChildrenCategories` is this class is just a wrapper for `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::getChildrenCategories`.
You can rewrite this method and add your attribute in the collection, but this method does the actual loading of the collection, so you better rewrite the method that prepares the collection.
This one is `_getChildrenCategoriesBase` from the same class.
Make it look like this:

```
protected function _getChildrenCategoriesBase($category)
{
    $collection = parent::getCollection($category);
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('meta_title')
    return $collection;
}
```

Here is a nice explanation on how to rewrite a resource model: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15921599/2047249

Comment: Excellent answer. Looks like I have a lot of coding to do.